# Is $A^2-B^2$ positive definite too when $A-B,B$ is positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

Denote $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$
If $A-B,B$ is positive definite, it's easy to see $A^2-B^2$ is symmetric.
Now the question is:

> Prove or disprove: $A^2-B^2$ is positive definite.

I have checked some easy examples(mostly 2x2), and now I believe this is true.
But we know here $A,B$ do not necessarily commute.
I tried to write $A$ as $A=P^\mathrm{T}P$, and then I know all the eigenvalues of $(P^\mathrm{T})^{-1}BP^{-1}$ all lay in the interval $(0,1)$.
Another question show me that when $A,B$ is positive definite, $AB+BA$ can also be no positive definite.
I can't move forward. Hint will also be appreciated.

Comment: I don't really see why $A^2-B^2$ is symmetric, can you elaborate?

Comment: Here by "positive define", I mean $A^\mathrm{T}=A\land\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n\quad x^\mathrm{T}Ax\geq 0$, so $(A^2-B^2)^\mathrm{T}=(A^2-B^2)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first question try:
$$ A = \pmatrix{2 & 1\cr 1 & 7\cr},\ B = \pmatrix{1 & -1\cr -1 & 2\cr} $$

For the second,

$$ A = \pmatrix{2 & 1\cr 1 & 1\cr},\ B = \pmatrix{ 5 & -3\cr -3 & 2} $$

Comment: Thanks, a good counterexample.